# Problema com o CORS - Preflight (get funciona, post não)

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, cors

Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema do CORS? Pois sinceramente já tentei muita coisa e não consegui, já coloquei no backend (php) ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN * e outros, mesmo assim o erro persiste, apenas para posts:

```
public static function HTTPResponseSet($httpStatusCode) {
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
  http_response_code($httpStatusCode);

  // Allow from any origin
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
  }

  // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");         
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
      // header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding");
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

E sim, estou chamando a função. Faço outras requests do projeto no localhost e funcionam, mas utilizando vue na porta 8080 com axios, e o projeto no localhost/projeto não funcionam.

Código request: `methods: {
    save() {
      let client = {
        name: this.form.name,
        description: this.form.description,
      }

```
  axios.post('http://localhost/usios_planner/project/public/client/create', client)
  .then(response => {
    window.console.log('Ok', response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    window.console.log('Error: ', error);
  });

  this.$store.state.clients.push(client)
  window.console.log('Client: ',client)

  this.dialog.show = true;
}
```

},`

Print do erro: https://prnt.sc/rzzb6i
**Erro:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
client:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/usios_planner/project/public/client/create' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Estou usando: PHP no backend, VueJS no Front e Axios no vue.

OBS: O código acima para ativar o CORS funcionou para requests que faço em localhost/pasta_do_projeto, mas no vue (localhost:8080) tenho o erro em questão.

Comment: Ok, houve um equívoco de minha parte. Pensei que o Guilherme tivesse entrado no tópico apenas para falar disso e não para "ajudar", por isso todo esse alvoroço. Mas logo depois ele respondeu abaixo a solução. Já pedi desculpas e agradeci, me equivoquei desta forma pois algumas pessoas entram em tópicos e apenas falam sobre assuntos do tipo e não ajudam. Já vi muitos tópicos aqui assim, de qualquer forma agradeço aos dois. Não postarei mais imagens de códigos.

Comment: Tranquilo, só quero que entenda que comentar orientando como formatar as perguntas também é uma forma de ajudar. Não no sentido de "*ajudar diretamente no problema*", mas sim "*ajudar o site a ficar mais organizado*". E **ambas são válidas**, já que uma vez postada aqui, a pergunta deixa de ser somente sua e [passa a ser "de todos"](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing), e por isso somos meio "chatos" em deixar tudo arrumado :-)

Comment: @Deyvid, No caso o Guilherme fez a orientação e deu a resposta. Mas olhe para o meu caso, eu escolho por vez vinte questões que estão fechadas ou em via de serem fechadas, eu as analiso caso a caso e deixo as orientações para cada autor melhorar e esclarecer. Dessas vinte eu consigo responder umas cinco por vez as outras quinze os outros membros da comunidade irão apresentar a respostas.

Comment: Então se a pessoa passa e deixa uma orientação não quer dizer que seja `chata` ela apenas esta lhe mostrando o caminho para obter uma resposta e se ela aparentemente fez a orientação mas não o respondeu provavelmente ela está presa em outra resposta ou fila de análise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Preflight indica quase sempre o que não foi configurado adequandamente, a sua propria mensagem:

> ... It does not have HTTP ok status.

O `HTTP ok` se refere ao código 200 do HTTP, significa que quando enviou uma resposta pra requisição inicial em `OPTIONS` não foi enviado com código 200, provavelmente com outro código e provavelmente mesmo não sendo POST e sim OPTIONS ele esta tentando executar o POST.

Em Preflight sempre duas requisições serão enviadas:

1. A requisição inicial OPTIONS, que é gerada pelo navegador
2. A requisição normal quando há alguma alteração inesperada, como em headers de requisição que não são comuns, por exemplo alterou o Content-Type do axios ou do $.ajax

Provavelmente isto resolva:

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    http_response_code(200);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");         
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
      // header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding");
    exit(0);
  }
```

Mas não tem como afirmar, porque você criou todo um ambiente de tratamento do seu HTTP e nem sabemos como é que o status foi modificado, logo o que posso afirmar é que em OPTIONS envie sempre o:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Que em PHP pode-se escrever com `http_response_code();` ou com `header();`

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Agora sim condiz. Muito obrigado, eu vou testar e caso dê certo irei marcar como melhor resposta.

Comment: @Deyvid ok, qualquer duvida comente aqui.

Comment: Pensei que vc estivesse aqui apenas para falar da imagem. Mas o que voce respondeu funcionou, então peço desculpas e agradeço pela dica tanto sobre o HTTP quanto sobre a imagem, alguns entram em tópicos apenas para responder coisas assim.

Enfim, funcionou, mas o post do axios não está indo, estou retornando o post e retorna um array(0), segue o codigo das duas tentativas https://pastebin.com/ZXXDuMVS

Comment: @Deyvid o campo de comentários é sim para dar orientações, você compreendendo ou não, temos um bom site e graças a seguirmos certas dicas, mesmo que uma pessoa diferente de mim tivesse vindo aqui apenas para lhe orientar, você deve sempre aceitar as dicas, pois elas ajudam não só a você, mas a comunidade do site também ;)

Comment: @Deyvid Gostaria de  um adendo. Fechamento, edição ou uma crítica ao formato da pergunta não são punições ou pegações de pé. São formas que a comunidade tem para regular e aprimorar a qualidade do conteúdo apresentado aqui no site. Os usuários mais experientes passam pelas perguntas identificando e oriento os usuários mais novos como melhorarem a maneira de expor suas dúvidas...

Comment: ...Tem muta gente que fica incomodada mas eu asseguro o objetivo da orientação é aumentar as chances de usuário a obter mais rápido uma boa resposta. Como são muitas as perguntas recebidas diariamente as vezes um usuário faz a orientação e outros passam respondendo as perguntas melhoradas. Se no futuro em alguma outra questão sua tiver um observação siga-a pois assim que editar a pergunta ela fica em evidência e outro usuário, ou o mesmo,  passará por ela e lhe dará um feedback.